# Calculating an integral with parameter with differentiation

Tags: calculus, integration

So i have this integral with parameter:

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty {\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{xe^x}}{d}x$$

I need to calculate $I(a)$ as a function with variable $a$ with help of differentiation.

So first i need to find derivative of:

$$F(a,x)=\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{xe^x}$$

$$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:a}\left(\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{xe^x}\right)=\frac{1}{xe^x}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:a}\left(1-e^{-ax}\right)=\frac{1}{xe^x}\left(\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:a}\left(1\right)-\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:a}\left(e^{-ax}\right)\right)=e^{-ax-x}$$

I do not know if i calculated the derivative correctly but i just wanna check whether this is the right approach?

So this:

$$\int {e^{-ax-x}} dx$$^

Is what i get and if i calculate it, i get: $$\frac{e^{-ax-x}}{-a-1}+C $$ i don't know wheter i should calculate the definite or indefinite integral i nthis part i used indefinite

But i was suppose to get this result: $$log(1+a), a>-1$$

So where did i go wrong. I shortened the calculations, so perhaps i missed something. But any help would be appreciated, thankyou in advance.

Comment: What about $\int_0^\infty {e^{-ax-x}} dx$  ?

Comment: Did not try yet. should i?

Comment: At least your derivative is [correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B(1-e%5E(-a*x))%2F(x*e%5Ex),a%5D).

Comment: Oh yeah, i will now write the answer

Answer (score 1):

@ MathIsTheWayOfLife : Your approach is correct, but don't stop at the undefined integral, compute the defined integral :
$$\frac{dI(a)}{da}=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax-x}dx=\frac{1}{a+1}$$
$$\int \frac{dI(a)}{da}da=I(a)+c_1=\int\frac{1}{a+1}da=\ln(1+a)+c_2$$
$$I(a)=\ln(1+a)+C$$
With $a=0 \quad\to\quad I(0)=\int_0^\infty 0\:dx=0  \quad\to\quad 0=\ln(1)+C \quad\to\quad C=0$
$$I(a)=\ln(1+a)$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can look at the Laplace transform:

$$\text{F}\left(\text{a},\text{s}\right):=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{1-\exp\left(-\text{a}x\right)}{x}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\exp\left(-\text{a}x\right)}{x}\cdot e^{-\text{s}x}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Now, using the '[frequency-domain integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)' property of the Laplace transform:

$$\text{F}\left(\text{a},\text{s}\right)=\int_\text{s}^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[1-\exp\left(-\text{a}x\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\space\text{d}\sigma=$$
$$\int_\text{s}^\infty\left(\mathscr{L}_x\left[1\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}-\mathscr{L}_x\left[\exp\left(-\text{a}x\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\right)\space\text{d}\sigma\tag2$$

Now, use:

- For a constant $\text{n}$ we know that:
  $$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{n}\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}=\frac{\text{n}}{\sigma}\tag3$$
- Using the '[frequency shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)' property of the Laplace transform:
  $$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\exp\left(-\text{a}x\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}=\mathscr{L}_x\left[1\right]_{\left(\sigma+\text{a}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sigma+\text{a}}\tag4$$

So, we end up with:

$$\text{F}\left(\text{a},\text{s}\right)=\int_\text{s}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}-\frac{1}{\sigma+\text{a}}\right)\space\text{d}\sigma=\lim_{\text{m}\to\infty}\space\left[\ln\left|\frac{\sigma}{\sigma+\text{a}}\right|\right]_\text{s}^\text{m}=$$
$$\lim_{\text{m}\to\infty}\space\left(\ln\left|\frac{1}{1+\frac{\text{a}}{\text{m}}}\right|-\ln\left|\frac{\text{s}}{\text{s}+\text{a}}\right|\right)=\ln\left|\frac{1}{1+0}\right|-\ln\left|\frac{\text{s}}{\text{s}+\text{a}}\right|=-\ln\left|\frac{\text{s}}{\text{s}+\text{a}}\right|\tag5$$

> Find $\text{s}=1$:
>
> $$\text{F}\left(\text{a},1\right)=-\ln\left|\frac{1}{1+\text{a}}\right|=\ln\left|1+\text{a}\right|\tag6$$

Comment: An interesting approach, but i haven't gotten to the zse of Laplace transform, nice to see there more approaches than just one

Answer (score 0):

SO after a HINT in comments i found this: 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-(a+1)x} dx = \frac{1}{a+1} $$ for $a>-1$

Then i use integration on $\frac{1}{a+1}$ and get the solution $log(a+1)$.
Sinc it's quite trivial in the end, i don't need to put more details on it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$I\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{xe^{x}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-\left(a+1\right)x}}{x}dx$$ so, assuming $a>-1$ we may apply the [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) and get $$I\left(a\right)=\color{red}{\log\left(a+1\right)}.$$